# Why checkbox is not binding value of object field (Angular 4)

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular4-forms

I want to bind field value in current object and switch checkbox depend on it value.

My checkbox:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline checbox-switch switch-success">
<input
  #livingRoom
  type="checkbox"
  name="livingRoom"
  id="livingRoom"
  [checked]="showDefaultTypeRoom.isExistLivingRoom"
/>
<span></span>
</label>
```

I change *showDefaultTypeRoom* object and *isExistLivingRoom* but my checkbox is not switching depend on isExistLivingRoom value.

How fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 2 way binding :

```
[(ngModel)]="showDefaultTypeRoom.isExistLivingRoom"
```

instead of :

```
[checked]="showDefaultTypeRoom.isExistLivingRoom"
```

Comment: I think if you wanna do it that way you should split the 2-way binding: `[checked]="showDefaultTypeRoom.isExistLivingRoom" (checkedChange)="setTheValue($event)"`

Comment: @Guntram , Sorry for typo , I was meant to say ngModel with 2 way data binding

Comment: Yeah, I know, typing fast to answer quickly :)

Comment: @Guntram , Exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="test.value"/>
```

And in TS:

```
public test = {value: true};
```

try here:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/demklkjdbqq

(or use reactive form style)

Comment: see here: `https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html#understanding-ngmodel`